# How can I make a building's walls grow as if its being constructed?

Tags: modeling, animation

I saw this Blender animation on Youtube showing a building walls grow into completion from the ground up:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lNSdnzUH9IY

Does anyone know how to achieve this result? I have a building model, just have to show the walls rising up and covered with the ceiling.

Comment: maybe moving up booleans objects for the walls and increasing array count for the tiles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the walls you could use a Boolean modifier:

- Create your walls.
- Create an object that will mask your walls, like a cube.
- Give your walls a *Boolean* modifier. Choose *Operation* > *Difference* and select your cube as *Object*.
- To make the cube invisible, go in the *Properties* panel > *Display* > *Maximum Draw Type* > *Wire*, and in *Cycles Settings*, disable all the options.
- Now when you move up or down the cube it will make your wall visible and invisible, you just have to put some keyframes.
- Repeat the same operation for the other walls with new cubes.

For the roof :

- Create an array of tiles, with or without an *Array* modifier.
- Duplicate this array of tiles with a new *Array* modifier. Put some keyframes on the *Count* Value to display more and more tiles.

[image]

Comment: Amazing! That does the trick! Thanks very much.